# How to deal with many2many using the Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using the [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/).

I have a **many2many** field in one of my models i.e.

```
 attribute_answers = models.ManyToManyField(AttributeAnswers)
```

This creates its only table hence I don't have mapped in my models.

However, I want the API to allow a POST to this table, but it does not exist in models so in view and  Serialize.py I cannot reference it. What is the recommendation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This creates it's only table hence I don't have mapped in my models.

I assume you're talking about the reverse relationship, as `attribute_answers` *will* be accessible from the model instance that it's defined on, and *will* create an appropriate default serializer field.

For the reverse relationship, make sure you set the `related_name` on the model field, so that you can access the reverse relationship from the `AttributeAnswers` model.

See here: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#reverse-relations

Comment: I get 'module' object has no attribute 'PrimaryKeyRelationship' with serializers.PrimaryKeyRelationship(many=True)

Comment: also on the docs here  http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#reverse-relations it states "serializer.ModelSerializer" do you think it means serializers.ModelSerializer?

Comment: You would.  Because it doesn't.  The field is named `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`... http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: 'it states "serializer.ModelSerializer"' Thanks!  That's a typo.  Fixed now and will be live on the docs site shortly.

Comment: o snap, no wonder you always answer the REST questions here, just realised you're the creator! I'm new to Python (few weeks) and the framework so I hope my questions are not too frustrating. I'm not doing any actual protects just learning Django and your API framework.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize that the `PrimaryKeyRelationship` typo was in the docs, I thought that was something you'd written.  My bad, I'll fix that too.

Comment: ok getting this, so last question here: on my model for  Products I have "attribute_answers = models.ManyToManyField(AttributeAnswers, related_name="product_attribute_answers",)" In the serializer.py do I add the meta model as AttributeAnswers or Products?